# How do I distinguish if two SocketChannels are from the same computer?

Tags: java, networking

is it possible to compare two connected SocketChannels to find out if they're from the same computer? I have a java program that needs to match two connections. Matching by IPs is not reliable enough bacause comparing IPs can't tell if the connections are from the same machine.

I've been looking for the answer but haven't found any.

Thank you.

Comment: Why is matching by IP's not accurate enough?

Comment: I mean it's not reliable bacause comparing IPs can't tell if the connections are from the same machine.

Comment: @user1265395 Of course it can, unless you are referring to machines behind NAT devices, in which case nothing can.

Answer (score 0):

Use getInetAddress().getHostName() on the socket and check to see if it is unique as well as if the ip address is unique

Comment: What if the IP addresses are not the same? Consider using 2 browsers, (firefox and chrome) which one uses a proxy and one does not.

Comment: True this doesn't work for proxies, but I dont know if any solution would be able to from a server perspective unless the client actually sends its own mac address or something

Answer (score 0):

If IP addresses are not reliable enough (e.g. because of NATing or proxying) then you are stuck.

You could consider implementing something based on a shared secret; e.g. using a public / private key or a SSL certificate.  However, that assumes that you trust the owner of the other computer to keep the secret safe and not install it on multiple machines.